# Keras | Batch generator for LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a Keras model that has an `input shape = (frames, height, width, channels)` and has two scalar outputs (see next code par). My model does use an LSTM, that is why I have to add an additional dimension.

```
height = 32
width = 64
channels = 3
frames = 2
img_shape = (height, width, channels)
input_shape = (frames, height, width, channels)
```

If have defined a batch generator as follows

```
def generator(df, batch_size, frames_per_scene=frames_per_scene):

    ### read data frame columns 
    # inputs
    img_list = df['filename']
    # outputs
    happiness= df['happiness']
    anger = df['anger']

    # create empty arrays for input and output
    batch_img = np.zeros((batch_size, frames_per_scene) + img_shape)
    batch_label = np.zeros((batch_size, 2))

    index = 0

    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):          
            for j in range(frames_per_scene):
                label = [happiness.iloc[index], anger.iloc[index]]
                img_name = img_list[index]

                pil_img = image.load_img(img_name)

                batch_img[i, j, :] = image.img_to_array(pil_img)
            batch_label[i] = label

            index += 1
            if index == len(img_list):
                img_list = df['filename']
                happiness = df['happiness']
                anger = df['anger']

                index = 0
        yield batch_img, batch_label
```

When I try to use the following method of my model.

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_batch, train_steps, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, 
    callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=validation_batch, 
    validation_steps=val_steps)
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-289c48f3bbf8> in <module>
----> 1 train_model(_episode=0)

<ipython-input-6-b4f2c2235a41> in train_model(_episode)
     56         TensorBoard(log_dir=path_tensorboard, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_images=False)]
     57 
---> 58     model.fit_generator(train_batch, train_steps, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=validation_batch, validation_steps=val_steps)

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     88         wrapper._original_function = func
     89         return wrapper

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2167                                 max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
   2168                                 workers=workers,
-> 2169                                 use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
   2170                         else:
   2171                             # No need for try/except because

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     88         wrapper._original_function = func
     89         return wrapper

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in evaluate_generator(self, generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   2278 
   2279             while steps_done < steps:
-> 2280                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
   2281                 if not hasattr(generator_output, '__len__'):
   2282                     raise ValueError('Output of generator should be a tuple '

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in get(self)
    733             success, value = self.queue.get()
    734             if not success:
--> 735                 six.reraise(value.__class__, value, value.__traceback__)

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in data_generator_task()
    633                 try:
    634                     if self._use_multiprocessing or self.queue.qsize() < max_queue_size:
--> 635                         generator_output = next(self._generator)
    636                         self.queue.put((True, generator_output))
    637                     else:

<ipython-input-5-b23230fc675a> in generator(df, batch_size, frames_per_scene)
     18             for j in range(frames_per_scene):
     19                 label = [steer.iloc[index], throttle.iloc[index]]
---> 20                 img_name = img_list[index]
     21 
     22                 pil_img = image.load_img(img_name)

c:\pyenvs\ca\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    765         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    766         try:
--> 767             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    768 
    769             if not is_scalar(result):

c:\envs\lstm\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3116         try:
   3117             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 3118                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   3119         except KeyError as e1:
   3120             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

> **Question**: Has anyone encountered a similar error?

Comment: How are your dataframes indexed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? I have a header and a index for each row.

Comment: Well, pandas dataframes have an index, like a MySQL database. Normally, this is an auto-incrementing integer. To see this in action, print your dataframe and look on the leftmost column. These are the keys in how you select items in your dataframe. It appears from the errors that Pandas tries to do a lookup and fails. Something like df[0] in model.fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error might come from how you have indexed your dataframe. Verify that you have an index 0 in `df`.

One solution might be to store the underlying numpy array into `img_list`, `happiness` and `anger` and the `pandas.Series` object.

This will give :

```
def generator(df, batch_size, frames_per_scene=frames_per_scene):

    ### read data frame columns 
    # inputs
    img_list = df['filename'].values
    # outputs
    happiness= df['happiness'].values
    anger = df['anger'].values

    # create empty arrays for input and output
    batch_img = np.zeros((batch_size, frames_per_scene) + img_shape)
    batch_label = np.zeros((batch_size, 2))

    index = 0

    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):          
            for j in range(frames_per_scene):
                label = [happiness[index], anger[index]]
                img_name = img_list[index]

                pil_img = image.load_img(img_name)

                batch_img[i, j, :] = image.img_to_array(pil_img)
            batch_label[i] = label

            index += 1
            if index == len(img_list):
                img_list = df['filename'].values
                happiness = df['happiness'].values
                anger = df['anger'].values

                index = 0
        yield batch_img, batch_label
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to solve the issue with your hint. As soon as I see that this solve the problem I will accept the answer :).

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I would have never spotted the problem!